# Javascript return false not working

Tags: javascript

Guys this code is returning false in a blank page after submit.What is the error of my code.

```
function send_serial(){
    //Check date
    var date=document.getElementById('date_field').value;
    if(date==''||date==null){
    alert('Please select the date.');
        return false;
  }  

}
```

Comment: I don't see anything submit-related in your code at all. How does form submission come into play here?

Comment: @Gareth
This is the form tag of my page.
form action="JAVASCRIPT:send_serial();">

Comment: And also, how is this function run? How do you know it's not returning false, but the browser just ignores that?

Comment: You shouldn't have action=javascript, you should have `action="page" onsubmit="return send_serial();"`

Comment: You should actually on have onsubmit= not onclick=. If this is on the form tag

Comment: @Alxandr It displays the word false on the page.And page becomes blank.Address bar changed to javascript:send_serial();.

Comment: @Lee: My bad, fixed. @Ceylo: Yes, that's cause you post your form to the url "javascript:send_serial()". The browser then runs send_serial, which returns false, and since it's run as the url, it then prints the results of that.

Comment: @Alxandr @Lee Yes it fixed the problem.but guys I have created 5 form submission pages on this site using above action= method.Everything works fine.This is the first time I faced this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your form tag should be

```
<form onsubmit="return send_serial();">
```

not

```
<form action="JAVASCRIPT:send_serial();">
```

When you use `JAVASCRIPT:send_serial` as the action, you're asking the form to resubmit to a page whose content is supplied by the result of the `send_serial` function.

The `onsubmit` event handler is JavaScript, not a URL, so doesn't need the JAVASCRIPT: in front.  If the result of the event handler is false, it will cancel form submission.  But you can't just say `onsubmit="send_serial()"` because then the result of the action handler would be nothing.  The action handler is basically a function body that is plugged into `function (event) { ... }` so you need to have a `return` in the `onsubmit` attribute.